# pass a model instance to a function

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

This is the first time I am using sequelize (v6) and generally JS. and a little Confused. I have this function:

```
  function userStandard(user: User, currentlyActiveRate: number){
      
  }
```

//User is now

```
import { DataTypes } from "sequelize";


import sequelize from '../../../sequelize';

export const User = sequelize.define('User', {

    email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING    },
    password_hash: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
    }

}, {
    timestamps: true,
    freezeTableName: false
});
```

I can't run/compile the app now with the following error:

```
'User' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof User'?
```

if i do user: typeof User

it compiles but what is exactly the issue? Why doesn't it work without typeof?

Comment: Is it Typescript or JavaScript?

Comment: @Anatoly typescript

Answer (score 1):

You should declare an interface for your model as well as a type to describe a constructor and call `define` as a generic method:

```
import { Model, DataTypes, BuildOptions } from 'sequelize';

export interface UserModel extends Model {
  email: string;
  password_hash: string;
}

export type UserModelStatic = typeof Model
    & { new(values?: Record<string, unknown>, options?: BuildOptions): UserModel }

const User = <UserModelStatic>sequelize.define('User', {

    email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING    },
    password_hash: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
    }

}, {
    timestamps: true,
    freezeTableName: false
});

export { User }
```